# Solving a sum using the hypergeometric function

Tags: summation, special-functions, hypergeometric-function

While answering [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3745150/series-with-coefficients-coming-from-beta-function/3745631#3745631) I came across this curious sum:
$$S_k=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n(n+k+1)!}{n!}$$
Which [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+from+n%3D0+to+infinity+%28x%5En%28n%2Bk%2B1%29%21%2Fn%21%29+) effortlessly evaluates as
$$S_k=\frac{(k+1)!(1-x)^{-k}}{(x-1)^2}$$
The partial sum formula it spat out involved the hypergeometric function ${}_2F_1$, shown below:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{N}\frac{x^n(n+k+1)!}{n!}$$
$$=\frac{(1-x)^{-k-2}}{(N+1)!}\big[(k+1)!(m+1)!-(1-x)^{k+2}x^{N+1}(k+N+2)!{}_2 F_1(1,k+m+3;m+2;x)\big]$$
I did some research on [Wolfram Mathworld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunction.html) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function) about the properties of the hypergeometric function, but didnt get very far. Indeed, the terms in the sequence satisfy the property that the ration between two terms is a rational function of $n$, but the first term isn't $1$ as requested on Mathworld...

Does anyone know how I can connect this sum to a hypergeometric function and thus derive the formula Wolfram Alpha gives?

Comment: If your ultimate quest is to evaluate $S_k$, then we do not need its partial sum. Indeed, using the formula $$\int_{0}^{\infty}t^ne^{-st}\,\mathrm{d}t=\frac{n!}{s^{k+1}}$$ valid for $k >-1$ and $s > 0$, for $|x|<1$ we have $$S_k=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}\int_{0}^{\infty}t^{n+k+1}e^{-t}\,\mathrm{d}t=\int_{0}^{\infty}t^{k+1}e^{xt}e^{-t}\,\mathrm{d}t=\frac{(k+1)!}{(1-x)^{k+2}}.$$ Alternatively, this formula can be derived recursively from $$S_{-1}=\frac{1}{1-x},\qquad\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}S_k=S_{k+1}.$$

Comment: Alternatively, but along the same line as SangchulLee's comment, note that $$S_k = (k+1)! \sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{n+k+1}{n} x^n = (k+1)! \sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{-k-2}{n}(-x)^n$$ and then use the binomial theorem.

Comment: @Sangchul Lee Fantastic work! However, I'm a bit confused as to how you got rid of the summation and simply put an $e^{xt}$ into the integral on your second to last line. The recursive definition is perfectly clear though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$S_k=(k+1)!\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {n+k+1 \choose k+1}~ x^n$$ $$S_k=(k+1)! \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {-k-2 \choose n} (-1)^n x^n= (k+1)!~(1-x)^{-k-2},~ |x|<1. $$

Here we have used $${-p \choose m}=(-1)^m {p+m-1 \choose m}$$
and $$(1-x)^{-p}=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} {-p \choose m} (-1)^m x^m, |x|<1.$$